# Возвращение переменной из потока

Tags: c++, многопоточность

Имеются два потока, которые обрабатывают массив и суммируют элементы по которым они прошлись. Как получить сумму от двух потоков?

```
int scanFile()
{
    //обработка массива
    return sumval;
}

int main()
{
    boost::thread_group scan;
    scan.create_thread(boost::bind(scanFile, v, 0, a));
    scan.create_thread(boost::bind(scanFile, v, a, b));

    sum = sumval1+sumval2 // нужно получить общую сумму
}
```

Comment: Используйте кнопку `{}`  или отступ в четыре пробела для выделения кода.

Answer (score 6):

Проще всего воспользоваться `async/future` (c++11):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future>

int scanFile()
{
    //обработка массива
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    std::future<int> r0 = std::async(scanFile);
    std::future<int> r1 = std::async(scanFile);

    int sum = r0.get() + r1.get(); // нужно получить общую сумму
    std::cout << sum << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Если нельзя C++ 11, то можно использовать `boost::async`